# Change the starting point of graphs (The Y-axis)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, math, plot

Dataset:
[image]

I have the above dataset. I need to plot a graph where the starting point of y-axis needs to be 0, irrespective of the values in the dataset. The x-axis is the index(Time) and y-axis is Jolt 1, Jolt 2,...

I have a graph showing 2 different plots (the blue curve starts at y=0). I want the orange plot to start from 0 too to compare the trends visually.

Graph:
[image]

Here is the code

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.set_index('Time').plot()
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```

How do I modify the code to get the desired output?

Comment: IIUC, you could calculate the offset between the first value and 0. then apply that offset to all y values.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `'Time'` column as the index of your dataframe:

```
df = df.set_index('Time')
```

then you can loop over the remaining columns and plot them with respect to the dataframe index. In order to make all lines start from 0, you have to subtract to each column the respective starting point at the index 0:

```
for column in df.columns:
    ax.plot(df.index, df[column] - df.loc[0, column], label = column)
```

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Time'] = np.arange(0, 0.6, 0.1)
df['Jolt 1'] = np.random.rand(len(df['Time']))
df['Jolt 2'] = np.random.rand(len(df['Time'])) + np.random.randint(low = -5, high = 5)
df['Jolt 3'] = np.random.rand(len(df['Time'])) + np.random.randint(low = -5, high = 5)
df = df.set_index('Time')


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for column in df.columns:
    ax.plot(df.index, df[column] - df.loc[0, column], label = column)

ax.legend(frameon = True)

plt.show()
```

### Plot

[image]

Comment: How can I synchronize multiple such graphs using dynamic time warping?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic time warping"? Please, be more specific

Comment: I want to synchronize 2-time series graphs which can be done using 'dynamic time warping' (overlap by finding the Euclidean distance of each of the points on the graph.)